# Calculating $P(Z^2 + 1 < 2.6)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

If $Z$ is $N(0, 1)$, use a table to find this probability: 
$P(Z^2 + 1 < 2.6)$

My first instinct is to isolate $Z$ on one side to get $P(Z < 1.26)$ which results in $0.8962$. However, I am told the correct answer is $0.7924$.

Am I thinking of this correctly? Any suggestions would be extremely helpful.

Comment: What happened to the power? How did you say $z^2 \to z$

Answer (score 2):

You made a common mistake. You need to account for the fact that $$Z^2 = (-Z)^2$$

We have,

$$\begin{align*}
P(Z^2 + 1 \lt 2.6)
&=P(Z^2 \lt 1.6)\\\\
&=P(|Z|\lt\sqrt{1.6})\\\\
&=P(-\sqrt{1.6}\lt Z\lt\sqrt{1.6})\\\\
&=P(Z<\sqrt{1.6})-P(Z<-\sqrt{1.6})\\\\
&\approx 0.7940968
\end{align*}$$

The disrepency between my answer and your answer could be because I used R statistical software rather than a z-table to obtain the desired probability:

```
> pnorm(sqrt(1.6))-pnorm(-sqrt(1.6))
[1] 0.7940968
```

**Using a z-table:**

Noting that $\sqrt{1.6}\approx1.26$ we have

$$\begin{align*}
P(Z^2 + 1 \lt 2.6)
&=P(Z^2 \lt 1.6)\\\\
&=P(|Z|\lt1.26)\\\\
&=P(-1.26\lt Z\lt1.26)\\\\
&=P(Z<1.26)-P(Z<-1.26)\\\\
&=0.8962-0.1038\\\\
&=0.7924
\end{align*}$$

which agrees with your solution.

**The desired probability is the area under the curve between the two vertical lines**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to note that $Z^2\sim \chi^2_{(1)}$ is a chi square random variable with one degree of freedom. Thus
$$
P(Z^2+1<2.6)=P(Z^2<1.6)\approx  0.7940968.
$$
For example use the R code:

```
> pchisq(1.6, 1)
[1] 0.7940968
```